# ubuntu server 18.04 setup restarts after entering manual ip (vmware, hyper-v)

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi, linux-networking, hyper-v, server-setup

Can't find any reference to this problem, so i'm asking here.

I am trying to install an Ubuntu server 18.04 in VmWare (same thing happens on hyper-v). When I configure the static IP, setup restarts as soon as the form is confirmed.
I used to get around this by leaving he address on DHCP, but dhcp is not present here.
Disabling the interface also results in restarting the setup procedure.
Does anyone have any idea why is this happening, and how to prevent it?
I have tried using different types of NICs

thanks

Comment: Why not just config the ip after installation?

Comment: Can't get past this point. Leaving it on DHCP or Disabled, reports that network configuration timed out, and it will not proceed.

Comment: Have your checked if the image you are using is corrupt? Try to download it again, the Ubuntu website shows you how to verify your download after the download starts.

Comment: The image is not corrupted - it passes validation.
I (temporarily) resolved the issue by starting a portable DHCP server on that subnet, but am not happy with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue yesterday with Ubuntu 18.04.02 on ESXi 6.7 ( I also use 18.04.01 bur issue didn't appear with that). When we leave dhcp we also got timeout, but when static was set it didn't restart. I found workaround for dhcp situation that may help you. Go to second console ALT+F2 in Ubuntu installer and execute dhcliet command. Then we go back to installation and continue it. With that i manage to set static address in installed system.

Comment: The problem was (among other things) that there is no dhcp server present.